# Usage of dollar "$" in xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

In the following piece of code, I want to understand what is "$type" here and how it is being used.

How this if condition is being applied using "$type".

```
<xsl:template name="CodValue">
<xsl:param name="type"/>         
<xsl:param name="nodeNM">category</xsl:param>                  
<xsl:element name="{$nodeNM}">             
<xsl:if test="$type">                 
<xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">                     
<xsl:value-of select="$type"/>                 
</xsl:attribute>             
</xsl:if>
</xsl:element> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this template, you need a parameter, another one is optional `nodeNM`. You can call the parameter like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="CodValue">
   <xsl:with-param name="type" select="123" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

or

```
<xsl:call-template name="CodValue">
   <xsl:with-param name="type">123</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

type is a variable in `CodValue`, so you can print it via

```
<xsl:value-of select="$type" />
```

or via `{$type}` in attributes.

Suggestions:

- $nodeNM looks like the name of a tag (html-tags if you produce HTML-Code).
- $type (if returns true from xpath, ie. if not empty) will create a xsi:type-Tag-Attribute.

So if you call

```
<xsl:call-template name="CodValue">
   <xsl:with-param name="type" select="123" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

Your XML will be transformed into

```
<category xsi:type="123" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` is used to reference a variable inside an XPath expression.

In this particular case, `$type` is declared earlier by `<xsl:param name="type"/>`. However, it has not been given a value so you will need to use `<xsl:with-param>` when calling the template to so that you can provide a value.

n.b. The variable `$nodeNM` was given a default value, so you don't need to specify that when calling the template.